# how to add some text to a static image programatically, Using MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, image-processing, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a static image of size 1024*768 with some logo on one side,

i want to have some text added to that image eg: Page 1, (on another side)

i got some code from

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        try {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            UIImage ii = new UIImage (Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl.ToString ().Replace ("%20", " ").Replace ("file://", ""), "images2.png"));

            RectangleF wholeImageRect = new RectangleF (0, 0, ii.CGImage.Width, ii.CGImage.Height);
            imageView = new UIImageView (wholeImageRect);
            this.View.AddSubview (imageView);

            imageView.Image = DrawVerticalText ("Trail Text", 100, 100);
            Console.Write ("Switch to Simulator now to see ");
            Console.WriteLine ("some stupid graphics tricks");
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

public static UIImage DrawVerticalText (string text, int width, int height)
    {
        try {
            float centerX = width / 2;
            float centerY = height / 2;

            //Create the graphics context
            byte[] mybyteArray;
            CGImage tt = null;
            UIImage ii = new UIImage (Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl.ToString ().Replace ("%20", " ").Replace ("file://", ""), "images2.png"));
            using (NSData imagedata = ii.AsPNG ()) {
                mybyteArray = new byte[imagedata.Length];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy (imagedata.Bytes, mybyteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32 (imagedata.Length));
                using (CGBitmapContext ctx = new CGBitmapContext (mybyteArray, width, height, 8, 4 * width, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB (), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst)) {
                    //Set the font
                    ctx.SelectFont ("Arial", 16f, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);

                    //Measure the text's width - This involves drawing an invisible string to calculate the X position difference
                    float start, end, textWidth;

                    //Get the texts current position
                    start = ctx.TextPosition.X; 
                    //Set the drawing mode to invisible
                    ctx.SetTextDrawingMode (CGTextDrawingMode.Invisible);
                    //Draw the text at the current position
                    ctx.ShowText (text);
                    //Get the end position
                    end = ctx.TextPosition.X;
                    //Subtract start from end to get the text's width
                    textWidth = end - start;

                    //Set the fill color to blue
                    ctx.SetRGBFillColor (0f, 0f, 1f, 1f);

                    //Set the drawing mode back to something that will actually draw Fill for example
                    ctx.SetTextDrawingMode (CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);

                    //Set the text rotation to 90 degrees - Vertical from bottom to top.
                    ctx.TextMatrix = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation ((float)(360 * 0.01745329f));
                    //Draw the text at the center of the image.
                    ctx.ShowTextAtPoint (2, 2, text);
                    tt = ctx.ToImage ();
                }
            }
            //Return the image
            return UIImage.FromImage (tt);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new UIImage (Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl.ToString ().Replace ("%20", " ").Replace ("file://", ""), "images2.png"));
        }
    }
```

the output i am getting as following

[image: out put of above code]

As you can see it gets completely stretched in terms of width, i need this to be solved Any suggestions ???

At the same time the original image has nothing in the upper part, where as after processing  it shows multi coloured layer, how to fix that ??

Comment: Do you really need to draw the text into that image? Or do you only need to display the image + the text on one view? This would be much easier.

Comment: yes i want draw the text on that image ....

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not draw your text directly to the image? Perhaps you can try this:

```
    private static UIImage PutTextOnImage(UIImage image, string text, float x, float y)
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new CGSize(image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height)); 
        using (CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            // Copy original image
            var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height);
            context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Black.CGColor);
            image.Draw(rect);

            // Use ScaleCTM to correct upside-down imaging
            context.ScaleCTM(1f, -1f);

            // Set the fill color for the text
            context.SetTextDrawingMode(CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
            context.SetFillColor(UIColor.FromRGB(255, 0, 0).CGColor);

            // Draw the text with textSize
            var textSize = 20f;
            context.SelectFont("Arial", textSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
            context.ShowTextAtPoint(x, y, text);
        }

        // Get the resulting image from context
        var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return resultImage;
    }
```

The above method draws your text at coords x, y with given color and textsize. If you want it vertically you need to rotate the text with rotateCTM. keep in mind rotateCTM uses radius.

Add this to your using Context block (before DrawTextAtPoint):

```
var angle = 90;    
var radius = 90 * (nfloat)Math.PI / 180;
context.RotateCTM(radius);
```

Comment: anyway we can draw the text on the bottom left of the screen? @Stefan